# getting error message System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified.' when try linklabel

Tags: vb.net, .net-5

im getting message error System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified.'when try to open link from linklabel in VB how do i fix this?

```
Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked
    Process.Start("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BT9h5ifR1tY&ab_channel=Earrapes")
End Sub
```

Comment: What Framework version are you using? What Profile are you using to build your app (`AnyCPU`, other)? Did you deselect `Prefer 32-bit` in `Project->Properties->Compile`?

Comment: im using framework version .5 about profile idk im still new using visual studio

Comment: If you're using .Net 5, then `ShellExecute = false` by default, so write something like: `Using Process.Start(New ProcessStartInfo("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BT9h5ifR1tY&ab_channel=Earrapes") With {.UseShellExecute = True})
End Using`

Comment: *"im using framework version .5"*. No you're not. The last version of .NET Framework is 4.8. .NET 5.0 is not .NET Framework. It is based on .NET Core, but the "Core" has been dropped because it's the only .NET there is now. When you create a new project, pay attention to whether you're creating a .NET Framework project or a .NET Core project and select the correct one. If you use .NET Core then you have to work with .NET Core, so make sure that you're using information that applies to .NET Core when you read documentation or otherwise search.

Answer (score 0):

Because Jimi has no respect for the people who waste their time opening questions that he has already answered in a comment, I will provide an answer so that everyone can see that they don't need to open the question.

When `UseShellexecute` is `False`, which it is by default in .NET 5.0 and earlier .NET Core versions, `Process.Start` expects the path of an executable file to be provided. If you want to provide a data file path or URI that will be processed by an application then you need to set `UseShellExecute` to `True`.

```vb
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BT9h5ifR1tY&ab_channel=Earrapes") With {.UseShellExecute = True}

Process.Start(psi)
```

Comment: I have a project done in  .net framework 4.7.2, the code works in windows 10  but in my new win 11 I have this error thrown on me, even if I make UseShellExecute to True                Dim lprprocess As New Process()
        With lprprocess.StartInfo
            .FileName = "lpr"
            .WorkingDirectory = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
            .Arguments = " -S 10.168.10.42 -P raw " + filepath
            .UseShellExecute = False
        End With
        Dim unused = lprprocess.Start()

Comment: ok got it working, it  was not able to find lpr.exe. Copied lpr.exe and its dll from windows\system to windows\syswow64 and it started working